# Can't ping website but can browse it

Tags: centos, web-server, ping, centos6

I have server with CentOS 6.2 installed. The problem is that i can browse the website on it, but i can't ping it.

What can cause this?

Comment: Why is that a problem exactly?

Comment: There is some desktop application which is integrated to the website and integration stopped working after this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firewall rules are in place somewhere between you and the server that are blocking ICMP echo requests and/or replies.

Comment: The iptables on the server are empty. I have even turned of firewall, but it did not help. I've tried to `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` but it didn't help either. And i can ping other sites from my computer. I'll try to check router configuration on server side.

Comment: can you traceroute to it?

Comment: @Aceth no, I can't.

Comment: what's the setup? where is your machine in relation to the server? and do you own both?

Comment: I just have a VPS.